Date format in excel changes when edit
I have a table with dates in the A column. These are added with VBA with this row
.Range(1) = Now

For background, this is a log function, every time someone change a cell in a specific column, a row is created in the "log" tab with date and the changed value. This works but something in weird with the date format.
This is what its look like.

And this can be filtered as dates, great!

But when I edit the date, seconds are added like and the date format changes.

And now they can no longer be filtered.

The format for the cell before AND after is like this.

How can I keep the initial format even after changing the date or editing the cell and still be able to filter by date?

So many questions/possibilities: Do you have any event-triggered macros in your workbook? How do you set the format initially? Why are the dates all left-justified? If you use a formula like ISNUMBER(cell_ref) on one of those cells, before and after editing, what does it return? Please answer every question.

If you want to keep the seconds, you can manage date type that have seconds in them, you can go to Type > Custom and use yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss;@ for the rows that require seconds. To my knowledge, the default date format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm, as such seconds will not be displayed in the cells (even though they are still present).
If you want to automate this via VBA, you can do
Range(1).NumberFormatLocal = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
Range(1) = Now

If you do not want to keep the seconds, you can remove them from the default Now timestamp by doing the following:
Range(1) = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

Best of luck with your project!

Thanks for your anser. Actually I don't want the seconds at all, but they are added when I edit the cell. I have tried to change the format to a few different custom formats. One strange thing is that if I write a new date with exactly the same format, it does not get treated as a date.

Read this answer about fixing how Excel displays dates. Try converting your text dates and times to an Excel datetime and then it should format how you want it.

My bad @Fredrik! I edited my answer, does it work for you? Do not hesitate to clarify your question with any additional information as Ron suggested.
